# How to Pass Username and Password to horde WebMail from Another Web Page

Tags: php, webmail

Sometimes i want to allow users to login to your own portal and i want to allow him/her to view WebMail without any additional logging. You can do that by simply passing the logging credentials in the URL.

The link you can use should look something like this:

```
http://yoursite/mail/login.html?username=user&password=pass
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do that :

- Curl (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
- PHP Session (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)
- Single Sign On, there are several systems for that, simpleSAMLphp is quite easy to setup. You must have good knowledge in server administration to setup this kind of system.